# TCP IP socket.receive, data received in .Net application but not in Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, tcp

I send data via TCP from a .NET application to Unity but all bytes aren't received. This is the case with a simple .NET wpf application with the same code. Why is there a difference in Unity? Both is based on .NET 4.7?

```
// Data send from .NET application: 
byte[] ba = memoryStream.ToArray();
var buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(ba.Length);
stm.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

// Data receive works in .NET but in Unity not all bytes are received
Socket s;
byte[] buffersizeinbytes = new byte[32];
TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8001);
s = myList.AcceptSocket();
(...)
int k = s.Receive(buffersizeinbytes);
int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthb, 0); // size of buffer
byte[] buffer = new byte[size]; 
int receivedByteCount = s.Receive(buffer);
```

Comment: Please add some more context to your code, for example, i have no idea what `s` in `s.Receive()` is.

Comment: What is the value of k? Keep in mind that Receive is not guaranteed to receive all bytes sent in one go. I don't see you account for receiving partial content.

Comment: receivedByteCount  is not equal to the length of buffer.length (buffer size). But it is in .NET. My question is more about the difference between c# and unity of handling TCP.

Comment: As said, there is no guarantee that a  call to Receive will actually get you all content. You'll get whatever is available up until then, to a max of the size you specify. The value returned is how much content you've gotten. If you know the size of the data sent, call Receive until you have all content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may seem confusing that your code works in one application, but not in Unity, that is not the core of your problem. You seem to be making the assumption that when you send chunks of data, you will receive them in that manner as well. That's not the case.

Calling `Receive` will result in you getting some data, up to a maximum of the amount you ask for, but you may not get all. The return value will tell you exactly how much you did actually get. If you expect more, you will have to call `Receive` again, until you have all the data you expect.

There are various overloads of `Receive` which allow you to specify an offset into a buffer. So if you're expecting 32 bytes of data, but you get only 16, you can call Receive again, with the same buffer, but specify an offset so your buffer will be filled from its first empty entry onward.

So it's not so much Unity that's doing anything strange, but rather you lucking out that all works without issue in your other application.